# Domain driven design - Document conversion application

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture, domain-driven-design

I have to create a document conversion application which has to be done using domain driven design.

Basically my application will receive data in xml\csv(as string input) format which is to be converted to a standard xml,json or csv format using xslt(as string output).

There are also some rules(stored in a relational database) which are applied to the data after converting to xml or json format.

The end interface might be Rest API or Wcf application.

But now I am confused as how I am supposed to create this using domain driven design.

What will be my domain models, will this include the rules which are stored in the database ?

and where I put the core format conversion logic, in the service layer or directly in API or wcf service classes ?

Thanks!

Comment: why is DDD a requirement? maybe ask the person who is imposing this requirement what he is expecting out of it.

Comment: Read about DDD and you will understand why your question makes very little sense.

Comment: Although DDD is awesome, you should have in mind DDD is not the answer for everything, actually I've even heard that depending on what kind of application you're developing, DDD could also be not recommended, as it could make it complex in a way it shouldn't. Assuming this is a school or research project and that's why it's a requirement, follow what @Batavia answered, and read about DDD. Otherwise, you may end up building something too complex for a small application. If you understand the minimum about DDD, you would be able to argue why they are requiring it.

Comment: Thanks, everyone for your replies.

Answer (score 1):

also get more understanding what kind of documents you are importing. I think document might be one of your domain entities. that way you can have a

```
static Document createFromString(string inputText)
```

and a non-static to

```
void writeToSjon(filepath)
```

method. but to understand ddd or your domain model you really should talk to your product owner to understand what problem you are solving. because that is what you are going to model. And maybe it's not documents you are modeling but  some dogfood grocery list, that just happen to be a xml/csv input.

Also look at the rules you need to apply. Are they just text formatting rules or are they allergy warnings for specific dog breeds. DDD is a lot about lowering communication barriers so talk to the people who give you the input/expect the output from your app.

Answer (score 0):

> But now I am confused as how I am supposed to create this using domain driven design?

You get together with a domain expert and define the domain's concepts, defining and using a 'ubiquitous language'.

> What will be my domain models[?]

The models should emerge from your analysis performed with the domain expert. Look for nouns and verbs in the ubiquitous language. They'll be your starting point for the classes and methods that will make up your model.

> ...will this include the rules which are stored in the database?

That's an implementation detail. If it's appropriate, store the rules in the database. If not, write domain services that encapsulate the rules.

> I have to create a document conversion application which has to be done using domain driven design.

This statement concerns me. You might need to think about managing your manager. Use the right tool for the job.